# How should I save data in deeplearning with nosql (mongodb)?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, data, mongodb

I usually use file system to manage data for my deep learning model, but one of my boss told me to make nosql database to manage data.

Datasets I use have m rows, and n columns of count matrix and column, and row names (over 30000 rows, over 30000 columns for each dataset)

I haven't used nosql database unfortunately. So I tried mongodb to make data model that can save column names, and gene names, and count matrix in one document, which causes size limit error.

What kind of approach should I take? Or is there any tips that you manage your data rather than through nosql?

Comment: The way data are structured in NoSQL is very different vs. SQL (e.g. relational) database; it is a long story, so better seek some professional help or tutorials to understand.